# I need a recommendation on timer relays

Tags: circuit-design, relay, timer

Mechanical engineer being forced to put on an electrical engineer's hat...

Basically I have 2 proximity switches (https://www.mcmaster.com/7674k27) and I want to wire them in series with a push-button switch. When the push-button switch is pushed, and if the proximity sensors are activated, I want it to open a butterfly valve (https://www.mcmaster.com/2522n17) for 1 to 10 seconds.

But since the proximity switches are 15-34V DC and the butterfly valve is 120V AC, as I understand it, I will need a relay between them.

I'm wonder if this will do the job or I should use something else (https://www.mcmaster.com/2809T461/)

Here's what I have so far:

[image]

Follow up question, as I understand it each circuit will need its own power source what kind of power source will I need for the DC circuit? will this work? https://shorturl.at/oJNZ0

Comment: Please try to figure out a schematic yourself, and then post it here, and we can check it.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/nghd4uD

Here is a simple schematic of the plan

Comment: Well your first problem is that that timer and proximity switches have more terminals then they do on your schematic. Look at what each terminal does and make sure it's hooked up if needed. Also note that that relay is delay on break, so the valve will stay open continuously if the button is held down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a solution using your suggested components is possible.

If you feed one sensor with the button, this will feed the second one in a detection condition.

The second sensor can turn on the solid state relay, this forms a kind of logical AND function.

R1 and C1 build a snubber damping circuit to protect the relay output.

The time the relay is active will be longer if the button is held closed. If this must be prohibited, a capacitor (10..100 µF) between OUT of sensor U2 and the relay input can help.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWdsrd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>